# NativeScript - Android run error "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1 requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher"

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to start with developing Android apps with NativeScript TS, but while starting a template app (drawer) it shows me an error just after webpack compiles:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

Dependency 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-29'
```

Sounds like it needs android sdk to be 31 or higher, means Android 12. I have installed Android 8.1 Oreo SDK, this is the one I have on my phone. I've read that NativeScript supports 2X versions too of the SDK, so why this error appears? I followed the instalation tutorial from the NS docs, tested my instalation with `ns doctor android` command and worked fine.

Java version: `OpenJDK 11.0.3` (it was required by Gradle)
Installed Android SDK versions: `25 & 27`
SDK Tools: `SDK Build Tools 33-rc2`, `NDK`, `CMake`, `Android Emulator`, `SDK Platform Tools`

Any way to fix it, a config change maybe?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after few tries and a video from Youtube I solved this problem by editing `app.gradle` in `%PROJECT%/Android/app.gradle` and setting sdk versions to 32. There was already such code commented, so I just removed the comments, like:

```
// You can add your native dependencies here
dependencies {
//  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 32
  buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"
  // ndkVersion ""

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 32

    // Version Information
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"

    generatedDensities = []
  }

  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

It solved my problem, after running `ns run android` it properly installs to my phone, even if I don't have Android 12 (api 32)!